# z-index isn't working for my dropdown menu

Tags: css, z-index

I have a navigation bar, and the dropdowns are absolutely positioned, but for some reason, they still appear behind all other positioned items, no matter what the z-index. This makes the menu both ugly and difficult to use on pages with positioned items. [Here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/limabeanbloom/pen/PoYbZja) that shows my navigation bar and the problem it's having. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Here's a small spinet of my css since I don't think you want the full 150 lines of code in my question:

```css
header nav ul li ul {
    background-color: #00242b;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0px;
    z-index: 1000000000; /* why wont this work? */
    overflow: auto;
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    overflow: auto;
}
#absolute { /* this is on top despite the lower z-index */
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 0;
    left: 20px;
    top: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `nav` element has `position: sticky;` but doesn't have any `z-index`. This means that anything positioned inside it is going to be positioning itself based off of that `nav` parent. If you add a `z-index` number higher than any other element on the page to that `nav` element, your nav will behave as you expect.

To use your example, the red box has `z-index: 1;`. If you add `z-index: 2;` to the `nav` element then your entire navigation will sit above it.

There is no need to have any of the children of `nav` z-indexed once this fix is in place as the parent element will positioned above everything else on the page already.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I've been having this problem for so long, I wish I'd asked sooner

Comment: Happy to help!!

Answer (score 0):

First, try not to use such a high z-index. Start at 1, 10, 50, 100 or so. That way when you have a really high element you want to cover all elements that gets the highest number

To fix this: remove the z-index from anywhere else and start with the element to want to be high first.

In this case

```
header nav {
   z-index: 1;
}
```

The default is `z-index: auto`.

Comment: the default is not `0` but `auto` and both aren't the same

Comment: not semantics. Read the sentence in the link you provided saying *if your element doesn't create its own stacking context* which make both of them different .. also check the duplicate link to see the difference ... and if still not convinced here an example : https://jsfiddle.net/r5adnf4w/ (the child element is behaving differently due to the difference between auto and 0)

Comment: *All this is not necessary* --> you are adding an answer inside a community website and it will be visible to many users and I noticed a *wrong* information so I commented to avoid any confusion (you did a contribution and I am doing the same). You are not obliged to reply to my comment and you can simply ignore them.  Like you are free to answer I am free to comment on any answer. This is how the website works. Sorry but I will not *move one* If I feel the need to comment in order to clarify things or ask for clarification.